# pkpass file cannot be opened from iOS

Tags: passbook

I know there are so many questions regarding this topic but I tried everything and I can't seem to get it to work. I am using the latest tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass to generate my pass and all my certificates are valid. I always get "Safari cannot open this file"! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check you have the latest Apple WWDR certificate.

Comment: I have the latest WWDR and my cert is valid.

Comment: Could you post some code ?